# Is it possible to find this limit without using L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Is it possible to find this limit without using L'Hopital's Rule?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{2}{x})+\frac{2}{x}}{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}$$

This is a problem that I came across in a Calc 1 HW. I consider myself to be really good at Calc 1, yet I am unsure of the solution. Hence, I find the problem to be relevant to the community. Here is my best try so far:

1. Use the trig double angle formula to change it to:
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2\sin(\frac{1}{x})\cos(\frac{1}{x})+2(\frac{1}{x})}{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}$$
2. Let $u=\frac{1}{x}$ and separate into two fractions:
   $$\lim_{u \to 0^+}\left[\frac{2\sin(u)\cos(u)}{\sin(u)}+2\frac{u}{\sin(u)}\right]$$
3. Cancel the $\sin$ terms in the first fraction and use the known limit of $\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{u}{\sin(u)}=1$ on the second fraction:
   $$2\cdot1+2\cdot1=4$$
   The problem for me is - doesn't the proof of $\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{u}{\sin(u)}=1$ use L'Hopital? So does my solution really count?

Comment: would you like to use $-x<\sin x < x$?

Comment: $~\sin(2/x) = 2\sin(1/x)\cos(1/x),~$ and $~\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1/x}{\sin(1/x)} = \lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y}{\sin(y)} = 1.$

Comment: This is pretty much the way I would do it.

Comment: There are proofs of that limit that don't use L'Hopital's rule. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has the solution completely correct. You are allowed to use the known limit of:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$
There are proofs of this that do not use L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: just let $1/x=t$ and you have the fundamental limit

Comment: "There are proofs of this that do not use L'Hopital's rule" That's a good thing, as you need to calculate this limit to learn what the derivative of the sine function is in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

As $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\frac1x$ and $\frac2x$ become very small so we can use the small angle approximation for $\sin\theta$.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac2x\right)+\frac2x}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac2x+\frac2x}{\frac1x}=4$$

Comment: Also, this is not a  valid proof.

Comment: @geetha290krm Why isn't it a valid proof? Sure, you can always flesh out more details, and you might not consider the proof _complete_, but I can't see how it is _incorrect_.

Comment: I haven't seen this "small angle approximation" technique before. I don't believe it is typically included in a Calc 1 curriculum, so I would not solve it this way.

Comment: @user3925803 it's basically $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.